# How can I change 'change' date of file?

Tags: files, timestamps

How can I change the "change" date of a file? Using `touch` doesn't work:

```
$ touch -t 9901010000 test;stat test
  File: `test'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fe01h/65025d    Inode: 11279017    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    x)   Gid: ( 1000/    x)
Access: 1999-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0100
Modify: 1999-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0100
Change: 2012-04-08 19:26:56.061614473 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Setting arbitrary `ctime` is not easy to do.  Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4537291/855954) on SO.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537291/setting-creation-or-change-timestamps

Comment: Both comments link to same QA on SO.

Answer (score 34):

You cannot change the ctime by ordinary means. This is by design: the ctime is always updated to the current when you change any of the file's metadata, and there is no way to impose a different ctime. To change the ctime of a file, you need to do one of the following:

- Set the system time to the ctime you want to impose, then touch the file, then reset the system time.
- Modify the kernel to add an interface to change the ctime.
- Access the disk image directly (e.g. with `debugfs`) and twiddle the bits on the disk (don't do it while the filesystem is mounted).

Comment: Setting system time and chmod worked for me. See script here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126992/setting-changing-the-ctime-or-change-time-attribute-on-a-file/17066309#17066309

Answer (score 18):

You have the answer on related SO question pointed by jw013, for extX, on *unmounted disk* :

```
# Update ctime
debugfs -w -R 'set_inode_field /tmp/foo ctime 201001010101' /dev/sda1

# Drop vm cache so ctime update is reflected
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score 6):

$ `NOW=$(date) && date -s "2030-08-15 21:30:11" && touch file.txt && date -s "$NOW"`

https://www.shellhacks.com/fake-file-access-modify-change-timestamps-linux

Answer (score 5):

[evandrix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4298/evandrix)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557160/383498) excerpted in the next line,
`NOW=$(date) && date -s "2030-08-15 21:30:11" && touch file.txt && date -s "$NOW"`
 
needs to be improved as described below :

In some systems like mine, `date` output doesn't give a valid format to set with `date -s`

> My system `bash` shell version : GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
>   My system `date` command version : date (GNU coreutils) 8.30

My system `date` command output and setting the date with this format is:

```
# date
Tue 21 Jan 2020 01:36:22 PM +03
# date -s "Tue 21 Jan 2020 01:36:22 PM +03"
date: invalid date ‘Tue 21 Jan 2020 01:36:22 PM +03’
```

So it is necessary to improve [evandrix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4298/evandrix) answer;
It would be better to assign the NOW variable to the timestamp value
change `NOW=$(date)` to `NOW=$(date +@%s)`

```bash
  NOW=$(date +@%s) && date -s "2030-08-15 21:30:11" && \
  touch file.txt && date -s "$NOW"
```

Adding `sudo` command for non root user

```bash
  sudo bash -c 'NOW=$(date +@%s);
                date -s "2030-08-15 21:30:11";
                touch file.txt;
                date -s "$NOW"'
```

or

```bash
  sudo bash -c 'NOW=$(date +@%s); date -s "$2"; touch "$1"; date -s "$NOW"' -- \
                "file.txt" "2030-08-15 21:30:11"
```

In this way for easy use, the filename and setting date are assigned as arguments at the end of the line.

Answer (score 4):

The ctime of a file is updated when any of the metadata is changed.

```
$ ls -l x.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ignacio ignacio 485 Mar 26  2010 x.py
$ stat -c %z x.py
2010-03-26 11:57:56.237068175 -0400
$ chown ignacio x.py
$ stat -c %z x.py
2012-04-08 15:31:33.682383575 -0400
$ ls -l x.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ignacio ignacio 485 Mar 26  2010 x.py
```

Comment: but how modify it without update it

Answer (score -1):

I use `ln` for this case. The meta data is changed to increase and decrease the reference counter.

```
# $file contains the filename
ln "$file" "$file.xxx.tmp"
rm -f "$file.xxx.tmp"
```

Here I use `.xxx.tmp` as extension for the temporary file and hope, that it will not used by any other.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your contribution. However, I don't think this is what the OP wants, because that could also be accomplished with the `touch` command shown. The problem seems to be that the OP wants to set the change time to an arbitrary value, as can be done with access and modification time.